# How to add a Spring project to Tomcat configuration using Eclipse IDE, so that Tomcat will load the index page from web.xml

Tags: spring, eclipse, tomcat, agile

I have a project imported as an existing Maven project in Eclipse, however I'm  having trouble configuring Tomcat so that it loads the index page from web.xml
User Yugerten tried to help with their solution, however I'm obviously doing something wrong and its not running, therefore I include the screenshots of configuration and error log.

[image: Error Log]

[image: Config]

Comment: @greg-449, @eminem; the issue is the tomcat plugin 'url' configuration. Set the url to localhost & port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

Add a plugin configuration to your **pom.xml**

```
<build>
  ...
  <plugins>
   ...
   <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
     <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.2</version>
     <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        <path>/myWebApp</path>
     </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ...
  </plugins>
  ...
</build>
```

**eclipse**
[image]

[image]
[image]

**Or via Terminal / cmd:**

mvn tomcat7:run / mvn tomcat7:deploy / mvn tomcat7:undeploy / mvn tomcat7:undeploy

Comment: Could you please take a look at the screenshots within the modified problem description as I've tried your solution and encountered a problem. Thanks

Comment: @eminem the problem is from the line 41 in the pom.xml (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9XSQ.jpg). solution: comment the line 41 & uncomment the line 42.